# Django rest framework Many to one relations

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I want to display a list of attachments related to a task. How to pass the pk(uuid) of the task? So far I tried this:

models.py

```
class Task(Timestamp):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Attachment(Timestamp):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='tasks-attachments/%Y-%m-%d/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task.title + " attachment"
```

serializers.py

```
class AttachmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Attachment
        fields = [
            'id',
            'task',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'attachment'
        ]
```

views.py

```
class AttachmentsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = AttachmentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Attachment.objects.filter(task=task__id)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('tasks/', TasksView.as_view()),
    path('tasks/<uuid:pk>', TaskView.as_view()),
    path('tasks/<uuid:pk>/attachments/', AttachmentsView.as_view())
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add `related_name` to **task field** on `Attachment` model, `related_name` is already there with a default naming done by Django but it's better to add yours.

`related_name` is the name of the reverse relation, so you can get the related objects from a referenced one, so it should be:

```
task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attachments')
```

that's why it has the value `attachments` as we will use it later from a `task` object, so the correct naming will eliminate any confusion.

Finally, create a **task serializer** and add `attachments` to it's `fields` if you will use ModelSerializer so it will serialize the related objects alongside with other task fields.

For ex:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attachments = AttachmentSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'attachments']
```